# Launching Xcode Simulator with jenkins user

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, jenkins

I'm trying to launch an iOS app tests through command line, from a Jenkins Job.

If I launch the command in my user's console, works ok, the command is:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme demoIC -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=E6954360-11D9-49E0-9008-A8EE6BA1ACFC'
```

It's supposed Jenkins uses 'jenkins' user for launching jobs, so I have done:

su - jenkins

And the when I launch the same command, I got an error:

```
2015-02-16 18:21:41.215 xcodebuild[3952:1303]  iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -10810
```

Comment: It seems to be that I cannot launch a process with GUI from jenkins when is installed as a Launch Daemon. How can I switch to a Agent Daemon if the agent is in the same machine?

Comment: I faced with the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Pavel, one workaround is to install a Jenkins Agent in the same machine as the master, and configure the problematic job (the one who test the app) to be launched in the agent. I use JNLP as the execution method for the agent ,with this base root : /Users/Shared/Jenkins/MACOSAgent

Comment: Thanks, @rtrujillor. I solved that problem starting Jenkins manually from iTerm via VNC after each system reboot (it doesn't happen often).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this, it worked for me:

```
xcrun xcodebuild -workspace $Project_Name.xcworkspace -scheme "$Build_Test_Scheme" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=13.2.2' -derivedDataPath './output' test
```

Comment: output here is the directory I put all my test reports.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)" 
before asking a question.